# Reload PHP page where <body> tag is set in seperate PHP include

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, reload, target

I have a page built of several seperate PHP includes. One page writes the  information and another writes the content of the page. The page with content has hyperlinks on it that are all set to open `target="_blank"` (I'm including this info just in case it matters.)

My problem is that the body tag sets the focus into a form field when the page is loaded but when you click a hyperlink, even though the anchor tag includes `onClick="window.location.reload;` the focus is not put back into the form field as it is when the page is originally loaded.

New discovery: In Safari, if `target="_blank"` and `onClick="window.location.reload;` are both present w/in the anchor tag then only the `onClick` is fired. It does not open the link it just reloads the page.

Am I going about this bass ackwards?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the url from `href` tag and open it like this:

```
onClick = "window.open(url,'_blank');window.location.reload";
```

or

```
onClick = "window.open(url,'_blank');document.getElementById['id'].focus()";
```

Comment: I must not be following your suggestion correctly as it is not working for me. Are you saying rewrite my anchor as: `<a class="abc" onClick="window.open(http://www.url.com,'_blank');window.location.reload;"` ? that's what I have done (along with many other variations) and it has not worked.

Comment: Try this: `<a href='' class="abc" onClick="window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank');window.location.reload;">test</a>`

Comment: well, that works in Chrome, IE & Safari but not in FF or Opera. they still do not reload the page so that it is presented as if you click on the reload icon or as it is when the page is originally loaded. specifically, the focus is missing whereas it is set in the body tag to be in a particular text field.

Comment: @LyleCrumbstorm hmmmm, could be version differences. Works fine in FF for me (dont have Opera)

Comment: probably. yeesh, meanwhile average Joe Internet Surfer knows nothing about the headaches on the backend while designers & developers try to present a pleasant surfing experience!

Comment: @LyleCrumbstorm: your frustration is duly noted and shared! :-)